# AUTO_INCREMENT in sqlite problem with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite with python 2.5. I get a sqlite error with the syntax below. I looked around and saw AUTOINCREMENT on this page http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint but that did not work either. Without AUTO_INCREMENT my table can be created.

```
An error occurred: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error 
CREATE TABLE fileInfo
(
fileId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255),
status int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (fileId)
);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is addressed in the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html).  [Question #1](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

Which states:

> How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT
>   field?
>
> Short answer: A column declared
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will
>   autoincrement.
>
> Here is the long answer: If you
>   declare a column of a table to be
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then whenever you
>   insert a NULL into that column of the
>   table, the NULL is automatically
>   converted into an integer which is one
>   greater than the largest value of that
>   column over all other rows in the
>   table, or 1 if the table is empty. (If
>   the largest possible integer key,
>   9223372036854775807, then an unused
>   key value is chosen at random.) For
>   example, suppose you have a table like
>   this:
>
> `CREATE TABLE t1(   a INTEGER PRIMARY`
>   `KEY,   b INTEGER );` With this table,
>   the statement
>
> `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL,123);` is
>   logically equivalent to saying:
>
> `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES((SELECT max(a)
>   FROM t1)+1,123);` There is a function
>   named `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`
>   which will return the integer key for
>   the most recent insert operation.
>
> Note that the integer key is one
>   greater than the largest key that was
>   in the table just prior to the insert.
>   The new key will be unique over all
>   keys currently in the table, but it
>   might overlap with keys that have been
>   previously deleted from the table. To
>   create keys that are unique over the
>   lifetime of the table, add the
>   AUTOINCREMENT keyword to the INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEY declaration. Then the key
>   chosen will be one more than than the
>   largest key that has ever existed in
>   that table. If the largest possible
>   key has previously existed in that
>   table, then the INSERT will fail with
>   an SQLITE_FULL error code.

Comment: I like this type of answers. You should compress it to RTFM :)

Answer (score 11):

It looks like AUTO_INCREMENT should be AUTOINCREMENT see http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
CREATE TABLE fileInfo
(
fileid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name STRING,
status INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

We just changed the order from

```
NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT
```

to

```
AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

an example :

```py
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE users(\
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,\
    user_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).