# Sqlite python insert into table error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

having trouble with these two functions 
was wondering if people could tell me where I am going wrong 
this is a separate function as part of a spider that searches through a website of house prices

```
def save_house_to_db(id, address, postcode, bedrooms):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('houses_in_london.db')
    d = conn.cursor()
    d.execute('INSERT INTO TABLE houses (id, address, postcode, bedrooms) VALUES (%d %s %s %d)' %(id, str(address), str(postcode), float(bedrooms)))
    d.commit()
    d.close()

def save_transactions_to_db(id, sale_price, date):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('houses_in_london.db')
    d = conn.cursor()
    d.execute('INSERT INTO TABLE transactions (transaction_id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, house_id, date, sale_price) VALUES'
              '(%d %s %s)' %(id, sale_price, str(date)))
    d.commit()
    d.close()
```

here is the error raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saminahbab/Documents/House_Prices/final_spider.py", line 186, in <module>
    final_function(link_set=areas,id_counter=40)
  File "/Users/s/Documents/House_Prices/final_spider.py", line 158, in final_function
    page_stripper(link=(root+page), id_counter=id_counter)
  File "/Users/s/Documents/House_Prices/final_spider.py", line 79, in page_stripper
    save_house_to_db(id=float(id_counter), address=address, postcode=postcode, bedrooms=bedrooms)
  File "/Users/s/Documents/House_Prices/final_spider.py", line 25, in save_house_to_db
    d.execute('INSERT INTO TABLE houses VALUES (%d %s %s %d)' %(id, str(address), str(postcode), float(bedrooms)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "TABLE": syntax error
```

and for reference here is the execute for the databse

```
# conn = sqlite3.connect('houses_in_london.db')
# database = conn.cursor()
# database.execute('CREATE TABLE houses (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, address TEXT,'
#                  'postcode TEXT, bedrooms TEXT)')
#
# database.execute('CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, house_id INTEGER '
#                  ' REFERENCES houses(id), date TEXT, sale_price INTEGER )')
```

as always, thank you for the support

Comment: In inserting to `houses` do you have a reason why you do not let the DB generate the integer primary keys, but explicitly pass them on insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many issues:

- [INSERT-clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) has no TABLE keyword
- You're trying to pass variables to an SQL query using string formatting; don't do it, ever – use placeholders, or [face the consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- Your VALUES-clause is missing commas between the value-expressions
- The [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) uses "?" as a placeholder instead of percent formatters
- "transaction_id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT" is not a valid column name
- "AUTO_INCREMENT" [is not valid SQLite syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508627/auto-increment-in-sqlite-problem-with-python) and you probably meant for transaction_id to be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` – also [AUTOINCREMENT should usually not be used](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The below functions fix some of the errors, barring the DDL-corrections to the `transactions` table.

```
def save_house_to_db(id, address, postcode, bedrooms):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('houses_in_london.db')
    d = conn.cursor()
    # Remove the TABLE "keyword"
    d.execute('INSERT INTO houses (id, address, postcode, bedrooms) '
              'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (id, address, postcode, bedrooms))
    d.commit()
    d.close()

def save_transactions_to_db(id, sale_price, date):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('houses_in_london.db')
    d = conn.cursor()
    # This here expects that you've fixed the table definition as well
    d.execute('INSERT INTO transactions (house_id, date, sale_price) '
              'VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (id, sale_price, date))
    d.commit()
    d.close()
```

Comment: thanks Lija, going through the corrections now, much appreciated. the reason I didnt do an autogenerator for houses, is that I thought I would need the number as a foreign key when inputting the transactions in the transaction tables and it would be the most efficient way to do that

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python) on how to fetch last inserted row id through the cursor in python sqlite3. You can then let the DB generate the id and use it for related `transactions`.

Comment: Thank you Lija, this is very helpful